# Varnish 3 not parsing regex pattern correctly

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm working on some code that generates PCRE patterns used to ban objects in varnish and having a problem with varnish telling me the pattern is invalid.

This is one of the patterns generated by my code

```
(?i)(((^| )page\-2[^ ]*($| )))
```

And this is what varnish is telling me

```
 0 Debug        - "REGEX: <missing )>"

13 RxRequest    c BAN
13 RxURL        c /
13 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
13 RxHeader     c User-Agent: curl/7.34.0
13 RxHeader     c Accept: */*
13 RxHeader     c Host: www.test.local
13 RxHeader     c X-Tags: (?i)(((^| )page\-2[^ ]*($| )))
```

I've even tried simplifying the pattern during testing to this

```
page-2[^ ]
page\-2[^ ]
```

And I get this

```
 0 Debug        - "REGEX: <missing terminating ] for character class>"
```

A simple pattern like this works

```
page-2.*
```

I'm running `varnish-3.0.2 revision cbf1284`

The relevant VCL is

```
if (req.request == "BAN") {
    ban("obj.http.X-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Tags);
    error 200 "Banned";
}
```

And, just so it's clear that the original pattern is valid
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It may not like the space literal. Try replacing the spaces with `\s`?

Comment: You should put this as an answer as it is the problem/solution.  Not sure why it doesn't like the spaces though.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.  The only reason I even thought of that is because flex doesn't like space literals either.

Comment: It seems `\x20` also works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently, as I accidentally discovered in my comment on the original question, varnish doesn't like space literals in regex.  The solution in this case is to replace the space literal with `\s`, which matches on any whitespace character, including spaces, tabs, and newlines.

Comment: While I don't like having to use \s as opposed to the space literal, this works for my uses right now.

Comment: Playing around I realized I could use `\x20` as well